# String Cannont Be Converted to Char

Tags: java

I do not understand why my program will not allow me to convert my variable into char.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!  I am getting a total of 7 errors all either based around my test score grades or around the test score keyboard entry.

```
public class lab13
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // declare variables
      int average;
      int sum;
      int i;
      char grade;
      int testScore;

      //Create a Scanner Object
      Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

      sum = 0;
      i = 1;
      while (i <= 4)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter a test  score:");
         testScore=keyboard.nextLine();
         if (testScore < 60)
         {
            grade =(F);
         }
         else
         {
            if (testScore < 70)
            {
               grade =("D");
            }
            else
            {
               if (testScore < 80)
               {
                  grade =("C");
               }
               else
               {
                  if (testScore < 90)
                  {
                     grade =("B");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     grade =("A");
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         System.out.print("Test score:"+testScore);
         System.out.print("Letter grade:"+grade);
         sum = sum + testScore;
         i = i + 1;
      }
      average = sum / 4;
      System.out.print("Test score average = " + average);
   } // close main
} // close lab13
```

Comment: Why don't you use a IDE like eclipse, so that it will report errors properly.

Comment: Use some common sense. What would it mean to convert a string into a character?

Answer (score 0):

A `char` constant can be expressed with `''` like

```
grade = 'F';
```

and

```
grade = 'D';
```

and

```
grade = 'C';
```

and

```
grade = 'B';
```

and

```
grade = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` can only hold a single character, which is defined using single quotes, as in `'C'`

Answer (score 0):

Insted of keyboard.nextLine() use keyboard.nextInt() and for character value assignment directly use character with single quota like 'A' instead of ("A")

Comment: Thanks for all of the help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class lab13
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // declare variables
      int average;
      int sum;
      int i;
      char grade;
      int testScore;

      //Create a Scanner Object
       Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

       sum = 0;
       i = 1;
       while (i <= 4)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter a test  score:");
         testScore=keyboard.nextInt();
         if (testScore < 60)
         {
            grade ='F';
         }
         else
         {
            if (testScore < 70)
            {
               grade ='D';
            }
             else
             {
                if (testScore < 80)
               {
                  grade ='C';
                }
                else
                {
                     if (testScore < 90)
                     {
                      grade ='B';
                      }
                     else
                   {
                     grade ='A';
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         System.out.println("Test score:"+testScore);
         System.out.println("Letter grade:"+grade);
         sum = sum + testScore;
          i = i + 1;
       }
         average = sum / 4;
         System.out.print("Test score average = " + average);
     } // close main
   } // close lab13
```

Comment: Use this code. Suggested Improvements: You need not use these many braces for if-else blocks if they are containing only a single statement.  And use System.out.println instead of System.out.print for output readability!!!!

Comment: if (testScore < 60)
         {
            grade ='F';
         }                            can be written as:                                                                       if (testScore < 60)
       grade ='F';